# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: migration, data

I'm trying to migrate from Magento 1 to 2 and when I get to this part:

> [2017-10-06 14:04:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
>   33% [=========>------------------] Remaining Time: 3 mins

I then get this error

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to delete this record from that particular table ? if not then do this after take database backup then perform.

Answer (score 2):

The problem should go away if you change `bulk_size` to something other than **0** in your **config.xml**. It doesn't seem to auto-detect correctly on the `customer_group` table. Setting mine to 100 solved the problem for me.

To find out what table is the problem, try adding some debugging info to your `src/Migration/Step/Map/Data.php` file. Something like `$this->logger->info("DEBUG: " . $sourceDocName );` around line 136 (in the **perform()** method, first thing within the first foreach loop). This should output the table the migration tool is currently working on in the console.

Comment: Great tip to add the debug line. Helped me proceed.

Comment: You should rather tell in which method not line, the line can vary depending on the version.

Comment: Thanks @Black, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error.  When doing the migration with verbose mode on, I can see that the issue is with the "**customer_group**" table. **Primary key 0** is the "**NOT LOGGED IN**" customer group.

That is how far I am into for now.  I will let you know if I find anything else.

Comment: How do you know which table is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. to get past it at least temporarily, I added this to the map.xml file under source and under document_rules

```
 <ignore>
    <document>customer_group</document>
 </ignore>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ignore>
    <document>customer_group</document>
 </ignore>
```

worked for me inside the map.xml (or map.xml.dist)
source -> field_rules node